# Would any of these phrasal verbs seem odd to use in the context?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, sentence-choice

Would any of these phrasal verbs seem odd to use in this context? Also, which one is the best option according to you?

1. The bank robber **handed the stroller back** to the female hostage, who then crying picked up her baby and gave it a big hug.
2. The bank robber **gave the stroller back** to the female hostage, who then crying picked up her baby and gave it a big hug.
3. The bank robber **returned the stroller** to the female hostage, who then crying picked up her baby and gave it a big hug.
4. The bank robber **rolled the stroller back** to the female hostage, who then crying picked up her baby and gave it a big hug.

Comment: Which one do you prefer, and why? We ask you to do some research yourself.

Comment: I prefer 3 and 4, if they can be used here. 1 and 2 appear awkward to me to use about something as big as a stroller.